# Previous business day/ year over year from null

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to pull year over year data by date from a database, but when the previous year falls on a holiday, the row is null.  For example, 5/25/15 is the same day previous year for 5/23/16 this year.  However, since 5/25/15 was Memorial Day, it didn't even create a row.  So, I need the solution to pull the data from the last available business day.

Any help out there?

Comment: What does your current query look like? Also it may be useful to have a calendar table for these types of queries.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcveYou will get quicker and better responses on coomplete questions.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are doing something like this:

```
from thisyear
join prevyear on thisyear.mmdd = prevyear.mmdd
```

i.e. joining on the precisely same month and day, when you should be doing something like:

```
from thisyear
cross apply 
(
  select top(1) * prevyear 
  where thisyear.mmdd >= prevyear.mmdd
  order by prevyear.mmdd desc
) prevyear
```

i.e. find the closest month and day that was before or even on the same day.

Comment: I want it to look at today's date, then go to the database and pull data for the same day previous year, unless that day is null, then pull data for the next previous business day with data (thereby overlooking holidays where no data exists).

Comment: Not same date...same day

Comment: Same thing, use a TOP(1) query ordered by month and day descending to get as close as possible.

Comment: The problem is the previous year month and day is null because it was on a holiday.  There is no row to pull from and calculate the next previous business day.

Comment: See how I look up a day in the previous year in above query part: I take all days up to the one I am looking for (`thisyear.mmdd >= prevyear.mmdd`) and from all these days I take the closest (`top(1) order by prevyear.mmdd desc`.